# PrimeNG Editor loses <br> tags when using FormGroup.patchValue

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

I've made components that toggle between edit and view modes. When they move into edit mode they patch their formGroup to ensure the form data is accurate. In Chrome, when I use patchValue the primeNG editor seems to lose the newlines (the br tags).

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
if (changes.editMode) {
  if (this.editMode) {
    this.formGroup.patchValue({text: this.text}, {emitEvent: false});
  }
}
```

Here is a plunker showing the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/igeMw9WfhW6Nq0uD6oPe?p=preview

Comment: Have you resolved the problem? I have similar one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72197616/primeng-editor-unexpected-breakline-behaviour